# \endlastheader in longtable?

Tags: captions, longtable, xltabular

I got code example from [here](https://www.overleaf.com/project/6429ebb5f850221d0ad0c288). I did not found `\endlasthead` in `longtable` package, but i want latex's behaviour as follows: if I have long table placed in 3 pages, I want usual title (caption) on first page, caption like `"Table N - continued from previous page"` on second, and on last (third) page title like `"end of Table N"`.

And if table placed in only 2 pages, on last (second) page I still want to see `"end of Table N"`. Can I do this? Desirable to have universal solution for any `longtable`.

Comment: not directly supported as longtable doesn't know it is the last page at the point it adds the head.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok, but maybe I can do it manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do it with `longtblr` of the wonderful package `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}     

\DefTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{default}{- Continued from previous page}
\DefTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{final}{End of }

\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot}{default}{}% no continuation foot

\DefTblrTemplate{lasthead}{default}{% last title
    \centerline{%
    \UseTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{final}%
    \UseTblrTemplate{caption-tag}{default}%
    \UseTblrTemplate{caption-sep}{default}%
    \UseTblrTemplate{caption-text}{default}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {My Caption},
    label = {tblr:test},
    ]{
    colspec = {XXX}, 
    hlines
    }
Head & Head & Head \\
Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
Phi & Chi & Psi \\
Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
Phi & Chi & Psi \\
Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
Phi & Chi & Psi \\
Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
Phi & Chi & Psi \\Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
Phi & Chi & Psi \\
Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
Phi & Chi & Psi \\Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
Phi & Chi & Psi \\
Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
Phi & Chi & Psi \\Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
Phi & Chi & Psi \\
Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
Phi & Chi & Psi \\Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
Phi & Chi & Psi \\
Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
Phi & Chi & Psi \\Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
Phi & Chi & Psi \\
Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
Phi & Chi & Psi \\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

First page:

[image]

Second page:

[image]

Last page:

[image]

P.S. = The link in your question is restricted.

Comment: Really thank you!

Comment: @DaniilRozanov You're welcome and thank you for accepting my answer